# inherited types cause an exception at select time entity framework5

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using EF5 code first and have types as follows :

```
    public class Region
    {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      //...
    }

    public class Destination : Region
    {
      public virtual Origine Origine { get; set; }
      //...
    }

    public class Origine : Region
    {
      public virtual IList<Destination> Destinations { get; set; }
      //...
    }
```

my EF context type :

```
public class JobAndPopulationContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Region> Regions { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to select all regions by doing a simple listing like this :

```
context.Regions.ToList();
```

I got this weird error message :

The relationship manager was defined with an owner of type 'JobAndMigration.Classes.Origine', which is not compatible with the type 'JobAndMigration.Classes.Destination' for the source role 'Origine_Destinations_Target' in the specified relationship, 'JobAndMigration.Repository.Origine_Destinations'.

What does that error mean ?
How could I solve this issue ?

Comment: Can you show some of the code that defines your classes, specifically the code that defines the relationships of the model?  With the way you have it currently coded, I am guessing you are using Code First.

Comment: i corrected spelling of your variable name. Origin not Origine

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at different inheritance types [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx)

For TPT, consider changing your context to the following;

```
public class JobAndPopulationContext : DbContext
{
  public DbSet<Destination> Destinations { get; set; }
  public DbSet<Origins> Origin { get; set; }  
}
```

Comment: Could you at least give me an explanation why doing that? and what does the error mean so I can understand your answer better?

Comment: With TPT you should only create a DbSet for the base class.

Comment: @MattSull87, Wouldn't only one DbSet mean only one table - and thus TPH? It is clear 2 tables are needed because there is a relationship between origins and destinations  ( an origin can have multiple destinations ).  Thus I am thinking TPT is more appropriate

Comment: No with TPT we annotate derived classes with [Table(...)] And create one DbSet of type base class in our context, EF will then create tables for base classes.

Comment: you're both right, I mean TPT is more apropriate, but from the link you provided, I think your implementation is a bit wrong, there are more things to do to force EF go with TPT. so please update your answer

Comment: I suppose that the 0 to many relation between origin and destination does not have to mean 2 physical tables... but it seems better to me. I have a similar scheme working myself - and thought I was doing TPT. What have I missed?

Comment: That should have read "EF will create tables for derived classes." I'll put up a solution soon.